# How to add an Exit popup window in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I need to show an "Exit" popup window in MOSS pages. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you describe what you're exactly trying to archive?

Answer (score 0):

- Setup a javascript include for jQuery
- Setup a javascript include file with this code:

`var doPopup = true;`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() { doPopup = false; });
  $('form').submit(function() { doPopup = false; });
});
$(window).unload(function() { onUnloadPopup(); });
```

`function onUnloadPopup() { 
 if (doPopup) {// do your window.open here }
}`

What it does is run the onUnloadPopup everytime the page is exited without clicking either a link or submitting a form. That function can open your exit popup. Be prepared for a lot of issues though. Exit popups are not liked much, browsers will block them and with something as complex as SharePoint you might get some unexpected occurrences..